# Obtaining css property's value using javascript returns unknown character

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the code snippet below, I want to extract the content css property of a pseudo-element `:before`. In this example content with value `\e917` is not rendered as something meaningful on view, but on my real example, it does, so the value I want to extract is `\e917`, and instead I get the questionmark character, as you can see in the js console of the code snippet.

Given that I cannot change html or css, is there a way to somehow obtain the original value of `\e917` in this case?

When I inspect the element in browser, I can see the exact value that I want to extract using js here.

```js
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#my_p'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');

console.log(content);
```

```css
p::before{
  content:'\e917'
}
```

```html
<p id='my_p'>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: `\e917` is ``, working as expected

Comment: the key was using .charCodeAt for each UTF-16 character in the string and push its .toString(16) value to an array to inspect later.. by the way it's clearly showed also in the duplicate answer suggested